# How to define a dynamic constant in ruby?

Tags: ruby, reflection, constants, metamodel

I'm trying to recreate a case_class (like from Scala) but in Ruby.
so I've tried

```
def case_class name
  Object.const_set name, Class.new {}
end
```

but I get:
    NameError: uninitialized constant ...

I have tried to find which method throws that error, but I couldn't find it.
for ex. redefining "const_missing" in `Object` but I keep getting the same error

Comment: With your code and calling `case_class('Demo')` it makes a class called "Demo" and there's no errors. Remember you'll have to do this prior to using that class in any code, or possibly loading any files which reference that class during parsing.

Comment: Yeah but I'm trying not to call it that way. It need to work without parenthesis, just like "case_class Demo"

Comment: Nope, can't do that. The only way that code's valid is if `Demo` is a valid constant, which it isn't until that method is done. Catch-22.

Comment: You can also set the constant from within the `Class.new` block, i.e.: `Class.new { |klass| Object.const_set(name, klass) }`

Comment: @FrankIglesias BTW, do you think this is a duplicate? Does the other question help you to solve the problem?

Comment: @Stefan I read the other question, but I keep having the same constant error. I'm trying to figure out who handles the constants that don't exist

Comment: `Yeah but I'm trying not to call it that way. It need to work without parenthesis, just like "case_class Demo"` - your code works throwing no errors.

Comment: @FrankIglesias _"who handles the constants that don't exist"_ – [`Module.const_missing`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Module.html#method-i-const_missing)

Comment: @Stefan it works!!!!!! Thank u very much